# How to extract Linux kernel data objects statically?

Tags: data-structures, linux-kernel, kernel, static-analysis

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to extract kernel data objects using static analysis tools, I found [CIL](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/) as one option but looks like its more embedded in to GCC and may not be feasible when we need to run it with cross compiler. I wonder if any other C parser would help me for doing such task.

Could someone please recommend me a tool/utility to do static analysis of the kernel source code.

Comment: Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has strong C parsers and can be used to build arbitrary analysis tools.  It has been used on systems of some 25 million lines of code, which matches the scale of the Linux kernal well.

Comment: Thanks Ira, but we need some open source solution for our research.

Comment: Let us know what you find.  You'll need a pretty robust tool to do the linux kernal: big, mean, nasty C code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to explore the parser in clang. I have the same demand, some people refer me to clang. Haven't got time to get into it yet.